# How do I input a keyword and return a category using the wikipedia API? (Rails)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I want to try and create a generalization algorithm where a user inputs a keyword and it returns the keywords category. anyone know how to do this using the wiki api?

i have this code in a model

```
require 'wikipedia'


class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.search(search)
    page = Wikipedia.find(search)


  end

end
```

and typing in Post.search("keyword") into the rails console returns a huge JSON version of the wikipedia page. I want to grab a specific string from it (The category). How would I do this?

Comment: what do you need help with? Do you need to know what commands to enter into the API, or are you more looking for guidance on your code? If you need help with your code, post what you've got so far, or give some more details, for a bit of context.

Answer (score 0):

I did this:

```
require 'wikipedia'
require 'ap' #awesome_print

page = Wikipedia.find("cats")
ap page.categories
```

And got this (the [*n*] is provided by awesome_print):

```
[
    [0] "Category:Accuracy disputes from December 2011",
    [1] "Category:Accuracy disputes from November 2011",
    [2] "Category:All articles with dead external links",
    [3] "Category:All articles with specifically marked weasel-worded phrases",
    [4] "Category:All articles with unsourced statements",
    [5] "Category:Animals described in 1758",
    [6] "Category:Article Feedback 5",
    [7] "Category:Articles containing Ancient Greek language text",
    [8] "Category:Articles that may be too long from February 2012",
    [9] "Category:Articles with 'species' microformats"
]
```